# Piping find results into another command

Tags: bash, shell-script, find, pipe

I'm trying to scan a file system for files matching specific keywords, and then remove them. I have this so far:

```
find . -iregex '.*.new.*' -regex '.*.pdf*'
```

How do I then pipe the result for this command into a remove command (such as `rm`)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167823/find-exec-rm-vs-delete

Comment: You don't need a pipe, you need the `-exec` or `-delete` primaries of `find`.  Also see [Why is looping over find's output bad practice?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/321697/135943)

Comment: @Wildcard , Thankyou, I realised that find had a -delete primary when I was reading through the man find command.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One way is to expand the list of files and give it to rm as arguments:

```
$ rm $(find . -iregex '.*.new.*' -regex '.*.pdf*')
```

**That will fail with file names that have spaces or new lines.

You may use xargs to build the rm command, like this:

```
$ find . … … | xargs rm
```

**  Will also fail on newlines or spaces

Or better, ask `find` to execute the command rm:

```
$ find . … … -exec rm {} \;
```

But the best solution is to use the delete option directly in find:

```
$ find . -iregex '.*.new.*' -regex '.*.pdf*' -delete
```