# `find` removed top-level directory as well as contents

Tags: find, rm

I ran

```bash
/bin/find /home/user/myfiles \! -name '.htaccess' -exec rm -r {} \;
```

and it removed everything *in* `myfiles` and the `myfiles` directory itself if `.htaccess` doesn't exist.

What I was expecting is that it would find and remove files within the directory, except for any `.htacess` file.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [No such file or directory With find -exec rm -f {} \;](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/415044/no-such-file-or-directory-with-find-exec-rm-f)

Comment: If you expected it to do something specific other than removing everything, then please mention this in the question. If you left something out of your command, consider putting it back in again for the sake of this question. The command that you currently display is applying `rm -r` on everything it finds, so it is not at all strange that it removes everything. I would also expect it to possibly emit error messages when it tries to enter directories that it has already deleted.

Comment: I am voting to close. As OP has told us that they have intentionally left out information that they know to be relevant. If they add it then we should re-open.

Comment: Okay I will add in the removed portion of the command that is working fine.

Comment: I’m confused.  Is the command with the ```\! -name``` clause “working fine” or is it removing the entire directory tree?

Comment: It removes the entire tree but only if `.htaccess` is not present as it won't remove a non-empty directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your version of `find` supports `-delete` and `-mindepth` (GNU `find`, or the version on macOS Monterey, or a few others), you can use those:

```bash
/bin/find /home/user/myfiles -mindepth 1 -delete
```

If it's some other `find`, I'd try specifying the path more like this:

```bash
/bin/find /home/user/myfiles/*
```

which globs things beneath the directory you want to leave intact and does the `find` beneath that.

It's a good idea with tools like find that essentially discover their own arguments for actions to run them with something nondestructive first, like simply listing things or doing an ls on them before deleting them.

Comment: Be careful with ``find …/*``.  (1) If you haven’t set the `dotglob` option, it will miss dot-files in the top-level directory.  (2) If you get into the habit of using `find …/*`, you might feel that it’s OK to use `find *`, and that can fail if you have files whose names begin with `-`.  And, while ``find -- *`` appears to work, it doesn’t offer you the protection you might expect.

Comment: Good points all, G-Man. My real recommendation for people with a `find` lacking those two features would be to get a better `find`, but I realize that's not always an option.

Answer (score 2):

`find` starts its search at the starting directory itself.  That is, if you have

```
foo/
    a
    b
```

and you run

```bash
find foo
```

you'll get

```
foo
foo/a
foo/b
```

So, when you do `-exec rm -r {} \;`, it deletes even the starting directory.  What you can do instead is tell `find` not to include the starting directory:

```bash
find /home/user/myfiles ! -path /home/user/myfiles -exec rm -r {} \;
```

Comment: While you're at using the non-standard `-not` predicate (standard equivalent is `!`), you might as well use `-mindepth 1` to exclude the start directory (depth 0)

Comment: Ah!  Didn't know about that (nor that `-not` was non-standard).  If you post that as an answer, I'll upvote it.

Comment: Is `-not` a GNU thing?

Comment: This did not work. It is still removing the directory probably because find returns "." not the full path.

Comment: Are you running `/bin/find /home/user/myfiles` or `/bin/find .`?

Comment: /bin/find /home/user/myfiles the suggestion to use -mindepth 1 works and is the correct answer.

Comment: I am not sure if ! works I tried -not and it didn't work

Comment: @DanielWalker, not just GNU, at least Busybox and [FreeBSD](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?find(1)) also support `-not` (and `-and`, and `-or`, though amusingly the FreeBSD man page is a bit unclear on if it supports the standard `-a` (though strictly it's unnecessary anyway)).

Answer (score 1):

[Daniel Walker’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/715648/80216#715651) explains what happened with your command
and one way to fix it
(and Stéphane Chazelas provided another option [in a comment](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/715648/80216#comment1356049_715651)). 
It’s good to know how to use `find`. 
But an alternative approach to getting this particular job done,
if you are using Bash, is

```
(shopt -s dotglob  &&  cd /home/user/myfiles  &&  rm -r -- *)
```

You don’t need `find` to do a recursive delete,
since `rm` has that capability built-in.

Comment: I am excluding other files that's why I am using find.

Answer (score 0):

You told it recursively remove `/home/user/myfiles/` `/home/user/myfiles/a` `/home/user/myfiles/b` you did not tell it to remove `/home/user/myfiles/c`. However, telling it to recursively remove `/home/user/myfiles/` is enough to remove everything.

The exclude (of `find`) does not say don't delete it. It says don't tell the command (`rm`) about it.