# How to remove every file and folder recursively except for a few specific folders?

Tags: rm, busybox, delete

Having the Busybox `ash` shell at hand, I wish to cleanup the `/opt` folder.

Cleanup means to remove every file and folder recursively except for a few exclusion paths that need to be left untouched.

#### Regression `rm`

```
# cd /opt && echo rm -rf \
   ./!(opt/etc/nginx|/opt/home|/opt/etc/config|/opt/usr/sbin|/opt/var/mlocate)
-sh: syntax error: unexpected "("
```

#### Regression `find`

This seems to do the job:

```
 # cd /opt && find ./ ! -path "./etc" ! -path "./etc/config" ! \
     -path "./etc/config/*" ! -path "./etc/nginx" ! -path "./etc/nginx/*" ! \
     -path "./home" ! -path "./home/*" ! -path "./usr" ! -path "./usr/sbin" ! \
     -path "./usr/sbin/*" ! -path "./var" ! -path "./var/mlocate" ! \
     -path "./var/mlocate/*" -exec rm -f {} \;; cd -
```

Any suggestion how to improve?
Use `-delete` instead of `-exec rm -f {} \`?
Handle `rm: can't remove '.' or '..'`?
How to delete the empty directories without recursion `rm -rf`, in other words how to f.e. integrate `rmdir`?

---

Note: it's Busybox 1.24.2 and there is no `shopt` neither `tac` available.
Defined functions:

```
[, [[, addgroup, adduser, ar, arping, ash, awk, base64, basename, blkid, blockdev, brctl, bunzip2, bzcat,
cat, chgrp, chmod, chown, chroot, clear, cmp, cp, crond, crontab, cryptpw, cut, date, dd, delgroup, deluser,
devmem, df, diff, dirname, dmesg, dos2unix, du, echo, egrep, env, expr, false, fgrep, find, free, fsync,
getty, grep, gunzip, gzip, halt, head, hexdump, hostid, hostname, id, ifconfig, insmod, iostat, ip, ipaddr,
ipcalc, iplink, ipneigh, iproute, iprule, iptunnel, kill, killall, klogd, less, ln, lock, logger, login,
losetup, ls, lsmod, lsusb, md5sum, mkdir, mkfifo, mknod, mkswap, mktemp, more, mount, mv, nc, netmsg,
netstat, nice, nslookup, ntpd, od, passwd, patch, pgrep, pidof, ping, ping6, pivot_root, poweroff, printf,
ps, pwd, readlink, reboot, renice, reset, rev, rm, rmdir, rmmod, route, run-parts, sed, seq, setconsole,
setserial, sh, sha1sum, sha256sum, sha512sum, sleep, sort, start-stop-daemon, stat, strings, stty, su,
swapoff, swapon, switch_root, sync, sysctl, syslogd, tail, tar, tee, telnet, telnetd, test, time, top, touch,
tr, traceroute, true, tty, udhcpc, umount, uname, uniq, unix2dos, unlink, unlzma, unxz, unzip, uptime,
usleep, vconfig, vi, wc, wget, which, xargs, xz, xzcat, yes, zcat
```

Comment: What needs improving?

Comment: @JeffSchaller To `-delete` or `rm -f {}\`? Write all parent paths or shorten it to the longest path and ignore that non-empty directories can't be deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
cd /opt &&
  find . \( \
    -path ./etc/config -o \
    -path ./etc/nginx -o \
    -path ./home -o \
    -path ./usr/sbin -o \
    -path ./var/mlocate \) -prune -o \( \
      -type d -print0 -o -exec rm -f {} + \) |
    tr '\0\n' '\n\0' |
    tac |
    tr '\0\n' '\n\0' |
    xargs -r0 rmdir
```

`-prune` makes sure we don't even enter those skipped directories.

We delete non-directory files in the other directories. And leave the directories to process for after (`tac` won't output anything until `find` finishes because it starts with the last line).

We need to pass the list of directories in reverse order to `rmdir` as we need it do delete the content before the directory itself. Note  that `rmdir` won't delete non-empty directories.

One usually uses `-depth` to process leaves before the branches that hold them, but we can't use `-depth` with `-prune`. For the same reason, we can't use `-delete` as it implies `-depth`.

Comment: It looks quite genius, first process the files, and when it's a directory print them with null separators for later processing. My bad luck as that this Busybox has support for `cat` but not for the reverse output command `tac` build-in.

Comment: Not having `tac` I'd prefer the longer and less readable command without `prune` and with `-depth` and `-delete`: `cd /opt && find . ! -path "." ! -path "./etc" ! -path "./etc/config" ! \
     -path "./etc/config/*" ! -path "./etc/nginx" ! -path "./etc/nginx/*" ! \
     -path "./home" ! -path "./home/*" ! -path "./usr" ! -path "./usr/sbin" ! \
     -path "./usr/sbin/*" ! -path "./var" ! -path "./var/mlocate" ! \
     -path "./var/mlocate/*" \( -type d -print0 -o -delete \) | xargs -r0 rmdir; cd - >/dev/null`

Answer (score 1):

## 1.

According to jlliagre's answer at [find - exec rm vs -delete](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/167823/find-exec-rm-vs-delete/167824#answer-194348) `\;` can better be replaced with `+` to optimize the `exec` clause by not running the `rm` command for each and every match present on the file system.

## 2.

It needs an additional `! -path "./"` to not generate `rm: can't remove '.' or '..'`.