# Pipe command output from a CRONTAB job deleting files more that 5 days old

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I would like to run a CRONTAB job to delete files older than 5 days in a folder **AND pipe the command output to a file in case of errors**.

This command deletes the files when run from a command line:

```
/usr/bin/find /mnt/SQL_Backups/* -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \;
```

but, when I add this to it to get the the stdout and stderr pipe, it fails.

```
/usr/bin/find /mnt/SQL_Backups/* -mtime +5 -exec rm {} \; > /mnt/output/CRONDeleteFiles.txt 2>$1
```

From the command line, error is

> -bash: $1: ambiguous redirect

while from CRONTAB email error message, I get this error

> /bin/sh: 1: cannot create : Directory nonexistent

I suspect it has something to do with my piping code?

What is the right way to do this?

Comment: that is `2>&1`  not `2>$1`. Also you can change `\;` to `+` to [speed up deleting by the find command](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/194348/72456)

Comment: Not sure how many times I looked at that line.  I must need glasses.  And thanks for the speed improvement hint...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stderr to stdout is redirected with `2>&1`, not `2>$1` as in your example.

Answer (score 0):

You could write to the logger,

```
find /mnt/SQL_Backups/* -mtime +5 -print -delete 2>&1 | logger -t rmsqlbackups
```

Since I've not provided a priority or facility (e.g. `-p user.info`) on my systems this gets written to `/var/log/messages` amongst others. The `2>&1` captures *stderr* as well as *stdout*.

Alternatively use your own method and write to a file, although I suspect you may want append (`>>`) rather than output (`>`), and here I've prepended all output with the current date/time so that you can see what was deleted when:

```
( date; find /mnt/SQL_Backups/* -mtime +5 -print -delete; echo ) >> /mnt/output/CRONDeleteFiles.txt 2>&1
```